# ColdFusion patch update 14 criticality

Tags: html, coldfusion, window, adobe, cfml

What is the criticality of Coldfusion Patch update 14 ? Is it having any major updates like tomcat upgardations as it had in update 12 or it's a normal one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple pages on the net explaining the details like [Adobe's](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/coldfusion/apsb18-14.html) own [pages](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/security-updates-for-coldfusion-2016-and-coldfusion-11-released/)

In short:

```
ColdFusion 11 Update 14 (release date, 10 April 2018) includes the following changes:

Security fixes, bug fixes, and other updates.
Addresses security vulnerabilities as mentioned in the security bulletin APSB18-14.
Tomcat is upgraded to version 7.0.85 and OpenSSL is upgraded to 1.0.2n.
```

Comment: I would say that any patch that contains Security Fixes should probably rank pretty high on the criticality scale.